# Allow admin to edit pages as a user with Forms authentication?

Tags: c#, asp.net, forms-authentication

I've recently started working on a site that was previously developed by someone else. The site runs on asp.net, and while I'm pretty good at c#, I don't know a lot about how asp.net works.

My goal is to make it so that an admin can edit a user's details using the same tools & pages as when a user is editing their details. This would that this line:

```
Membership.GetUser() // returns currently logged in user
```

returns the regular-user that the admin is trying to edit, rather than returning the admin itself. If this is possible it would be very easy for me to add admin functionality to the site.

If this isn't possible, I will have to rewrite various functions on my site to look like this instead:

```
MembershipUser user;
if (Roles.isUserInRole("admin")) {
    user = Utility.GetTheUserTheAdminIsEditing();
}
else {
    user = Membership.GetUser();
}
```

If I have to do it like this, how should I implement `Utility.GetTheUserTheAdminIsEditing()` ?

At the moment, there is a login function like this:

```
private static bool _DoLogin(String user, String pass)
{          
    bool isAuthenticated = Membership.ValidateUser(user, pass.Trim());

    if (isAuthenticated == true)
    {
        // Create the authentication ticket
        FormsAuthenticationTicket authTicket = new
                FormsAuthenticationTicket(1,                          // version
                                        user,                       // user name
                                        DateTime.Now,               // creation
                                        DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(60),// Expiration
                                        false,                      // Persistent
                                        "");                    // User data


        // Now encrypt the ticket.
        string encryptedTicket = FormsAuthentication.Encrypt(authTicket);
        // Create a cookie and add the encrypted ticket to the 
        // cookie as data.
        HttpCookie authCookie =
                        new HttpCookie(FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName,
                                    encryptedTicket);


        // Add the cookie to the outgoing cookies collection. 
        HttpContext.Current.Response.Cookies.Add(authCookie);

        FormsIdentity id = new FormsIdentity(authTicket);
        // This principal will flow throughout the request.
        System.Security.Principal.GenericPrincipal principal = new System.Security.Principal.GenericPrincipal(id, Roles.GetRolesForUser(user));
        // Attach the new principal object to the current HttpContext object
        HttpContext.Current.User = principal;

        return true;
    }
    else
        return false;
}
```

How should I implement this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution i see fit is to create an administrator page (only visible to him) with the list of all users and then the administrator could edit them.

You could place this admin page in a new folder in your site then create a web.config file in that folder with this lines:

```
<system.web>
<authorization>

<allow roles="Admin"/> //Allows users in Admin role
<deny users="*"/> // deny everyone else

</authorization>
</system.web>
```

Or you could add this to the main web.config

```
<location path="AdminFolder">

    <system.web>
    <authorization>

    <allow roles="Admin"/> //Allows users in Admin role
    <deny users="*"/> // deny everyone else

    </authorization>
    </system.web>

</location>
```

Or even you could simply show\hide the admin link with `Roles.isUserInRole("admin"))`

Comment: Thanks for your comments. I want to avoid making a separate admin page if possible, as there are many configuration options for a user, spread over several pages. If I made an admin page, I'd have to clone all of this functionality, and the site would become harder to maintain.